# Swapping tokens with code

Tags: solidity, web3js, cpp-ethereum, pancakeswap, vyper

how do I swap tokens using java script in pancake swap v3 I'm looking for source code but not finding it anywhere

Comment: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-v3-contracts is this what you're looking for?

Comment: hmm not really i'm not too good with modifying solidity, i want to swap a token listed on pancakeswap liquidity pool, but its locked on normal swapping using the website for the main time because they are on their pre-sale ,so i'm looking for a basic swap code basically written in js or i use fake_phishing2019 to swap if i could find either of the two i would be greatful thanks.

Comment: what ever way i just want to make a trade on pancakeswap v2,v3 both works, using simple js or any alternative